# SQL - Counting number of friends

Tags: sql-server

I have a table representing sending msgs between friends on FB:

```
    Sender    Receiver   Msgs #

     Dave       John        6     
     John       Dave        1    
     Sam        Dave        2   
     Mark       Ash         1    
     Ash        Dave        3 
     Mark       Steve       8
```

What is an SQL query to show how many have 1,2,3... friends:

```
    Num of friends       Quantity
          3                 1
          2                 2
          1                 3
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there will be better script to achieve it but this may be a starting point (as it returns what you are expecting).

```
create table #txt (sender varchar(40), receiver varchar(40))
insert into #txt values ('Dave','John'),('John','Dave'),('Sam','Dave'),('Mark','Ash'),('Ash','Dave'),('Mark','Steve');

-- Getting all possible pairs
select distinct sender,receiver into #tmp_full from #txt
insert into #tmp_full
select receiver, sender from #txt

-- Putting all distinct pair into a temp table (could be a CTE as well)
select distinct * into #Final from #tmp_full
go

-- Counting nb of friend for each and then grouping on that count
with a as (
select  count(1) "Num"  from #Final
group by sender)
select Num, count(1) as "Quantity" from a
group by Num

drop table #txt
drop table #tmp_full
drop table #Final
```

Comment: The `#Final` data set could be obtained using just `SELECT sender, receiver INTO #Final FROM #txt UNION SELECT receiver, sender FROM #txt;`.